# SignOutAsync deletes cookie but is regenerated when returning to client application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

this is how the logout is done within the api:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task Logout(LogoutRequest logoutContext)
    {
        if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            var prop = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = logoutContext.PostLogoutRedirectUri
            };

            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, prop);
            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
        }
    }
```

in the client app I have the following configuration:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options => { options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";  })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = model.Authority;
            options.ClientId = model.ClientId;
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.ResponseType = "id_token token";
            options.Scope.Add("openid profile");
        });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("User", p => p.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireRole("User"));
        });
```

when I log out the cookie is deleted, once I navigate back to the client I am not prompted to log back in and the cookie has returned. is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't deleting the single sign on cookie generated in your Identity Provider. Your client is redirecting to your Identity Provider and redirecting again to your client with a new authentication since your Identity Provider still maintains the Cookie. Capture the requests in Fiddler to see the automatic redirections.

You should signout from oidc too in order to delete this Cookie:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
```

If your want to signout automatically (without the Logout view from your Identity Provider) you can set false `ShowLogoutPrompt` and set true `AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut` in the AccountOptions.cs file.

Comment: I have attempted to add in this line, but the same situation seems to be occuring. From my client application I am not passing a scheme (i.e. just calling ```await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();```). Do I need to pass in a scheme?

Comment: Yes, you need to call SignOutAsync twice, one time for each scheme ("Cookies" and "oidc")

Comment: In both the client and api?

Comment: The logout is only in your client.

Comment: Oh, well I've definitely configured it wrong then. I am calling signoutasync in the client which then hits the logout method within the identity api which then calls signoutasync on the oidc scheme and then the cookie scheme.

Comment: the devs seem to have called the signout method inside the api in the ui quickstart guide (logout method): https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs

Comment: Your client have to sign out "Cookies" for deleting his own Cookie and "oidc" to be redirected to de Identity Provider. Then you'll click Logout in your Identity Provider to signout "idsrv". This is the controller that you mention.

Comment: when attempting to sign out via oidc I get an error when trying to redirect as the redirecturi is no longer passed, however this comes through when signing out of my cookie scheme alone?

Comment: okay I see what you're saying now, logging out of my cookie scheme does not hit identity server just deletes the cookie alone. I need to work out how to redirect from the end session endpoint. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but that redirection should be automatically done by the OpenIdConnect Authentication Handler when you signout "oidc". The request is made by using the configuration you set in options (authority, clientid, scopes...)

Comment: I usually use this: ```return new SignOutResult(new[] { "Cookies", "oidc" });```

Comment: the logout context is missing some essential information, this is the information passed when I get the context by id (```await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId)```) ```[INF] LogoutContext (RedirectUrl:, ClientId: , SessionId: c3268082b2c3e4956eed27df0473897a, ClientName: )```

Comment: returning the SignOutResult in the client doesn't seem to have helped unfortunately.